# How Can I Download A Computer Backup?

Tags: google-drive, backup

Using [Backup and Sync by Google](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/), I had backed up my prior computer (a Mac Mini) to Google Drive (I have a lot of storage). Now, I just got my new computer (a Macbook Pro), and I'm having trouble downloading the backup. When I try to do the usual right click and download, the zipping of the folder always takes forever and times out (I've left the computer on overnight, making sure it won't turn off and it always tells me that the zip failed).

Is there a better way to do this? I tried [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/) but it doesn't access the Computer section of Google Drive.

[image: My Computers on Google Drive]

Comment: why not synch it with your new computer instead of downloading a backup?

Comment: @user0 I'm trying to restore the data from the old computer

Comment: I got it... see akostar's answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a large folder, downloading as a zip from Google will often time out due to Google converting all the Gdoc files and then splitting all your files in that folder into 2GB  Zip files. (Have done many times before)

I would recommend installing backup and Sync onto your new Macbook Pro, not selecting any folders on the first step (My Macbook) - this is asking what you want to send into the cloud.

But then on step 3 selecting sync My Drive to this computer, and sync all your files. After it is completed downloading from Google drive you can move them where you like out of the Google drive folder and exit the Backup and Sync.

(I've done this recently from Macbook to iMac, and can say it is the easiest and fastest way by far)

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue just happen to me today. I had a ***500gb*** folder of music, family memories etc that kept timing out on me when trying to ZIP.

Not sure if you ever found a solution for it but I'll post a solution here that worked for me for future internet travellers.

Open your Drive account in the web browser. As you said before, the My Computers section is separate from the My Drive section (which appears in Backup&Sync)

In the web-browser you are actually able to drag and drop the files/folders from the My Computer section into the My Drive section. It's instant and basically allows you to see those files in Backup&Sync.

1. Make a new folder in your My Drive section of Google Drive. (eg "New Folder"
2. Navigate to your My Computer back up files in a web browser.
3. Open the drop-down folder list on the left to see your newly made folder (New Folder) in My Drive.
4. Drag and drop the folders/files into the "New Folder"
5. Restart the Backup&Sync desktop client and navigate to preferences.
6. See your "New Folder" and all it's files available for syncing across!

Big shout to Rocky from Google One support who told me this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found a two steps solution. Say I want to sync **DOWN** a folder from another computer that is on: `Computers > My Computer A > FolderA`.

1. In the new computer, install *Backup & Sync*, create a new empty folder `FolderB` and connect with the app. On the web interface is going to show on `Computers > My Computer B > FolderB`.
2. Using the web interface of Google Drive drag every **CHILD** of `FolderA` and drop into `FolderB`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of downloading the data, try **Google**'s [Backup and Sync](https://www.google.com/drive/download/backup-and-sync/) if you want uninterrupted download.

1. At first, Download **Backup and Sync** and Install it.
2. Run the client, log in to your **Google Account** where you backed up your files.
3. You will be asked to choose files you want to send to **Google Drive**. You may skip this if you want.
4. Then while selecting the files to sync from the **Google Drive**, choose the folders you backed up from your **Mac Mini**, or you can select all to sync to your current PC.

Now you are done and all your files will seamlessly be downloaded to your new PC in the background as long as you have internet connection.